# Firefox not opening pdf files

Tags: firefox, pdf, firefox-extensions, pdf-reader

I've been using pdf.js in Firefox for some time  (Firefox 38.0.5 currently and Windows 7) and pdf.js was ok. However lately, I noticed that pdf.js isn't being opened anymore and instead nothing happens.

I dediced to go into my Applications and set so it never opens in PDF.js 
However I noticed this:

[image: Two PDF content types, one Firefox]

To make matters worse, the settings displayed on picture, aren't applied until PDF.js is uninstalled.

I'd like to keep PDF.js for PDFs, but I haven't found a solution.

EDIT: A synced version of Firefox 38.0.5 on Windows XP works fine. Additionally I attempted to refresh Firefox and it didn't work, although the screeenshot from above only shows one file type.

Comment: Is there some specific reason you need to use PDF.js rather than the Adobe Acrobat plug-in?

Comment: Other than preference? No.

Comment: What is `pdfjs.disabled` set to in about:config ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing the Action for "Portable Document Format (PDF)" from "Always ask" to "Preview in Firefox" as described in this Mozilla [support article](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-repeatedly-opens-empty-tabs-or-windows#w_change-the-action-for-a-content-type).